# Search for last occurence of an duplicated item in a Range (Column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok - here's a snap shot ... I have a table that contains the following:

```
id      pkey        id2     pkey3           pkey4   Countif-From    From Key Dependencies
205591  STE-79      211366  CALMS-14380     1       STE-79
203477  STE-2       212513  CALMS-14384     1       STE-2
205520  STCOVA-156  56174   CALMS-7175      1       STCOVA-156
205524  STCOVA-158  56174   CALMS-7175      2       STCOVA-156, STCOVA-158
205523  STG-577     56174   CALMS-7175      3       STG-577, STCOVA-158, STCOVA-156
203973  STB-914     204238  CON-6749        1       STB-914
166482  TV-388      159643  ET-14180        1       TV-388
```

I want to search this table matching on pkey3 - but the value I want to return is an item in the  'From Key Dependency' column (which is a concatenated list of the ALL the User Stories in the pkey column) that are related to the items in the pkey3 column. Example:

CALMS-7175 appears (3) times in the pkey column - I want to return a String that has ALL the related User Stories found in the pkey column separated by ','.

The challenge is ... index (match()) will return the FIRST occurrence of CALMS-7175 that it finds in the pkey column but what I really need is LAST occurrence of CALMS-7175 ... and the related 'From Key Dependency' column.

Observations?

Answer (score 3):

Use this to get the row containing the last instance of "CALMS-7175":

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D="CALMS-7175"),ROW(D:D))`

Comment: If you just want the row number MATCH is easier, i.e. `=MATCH(2,1/(D:D="CALMS-7175"))`

Comment: None of those seemed to work ... not sure what the 'divide' function is all about ... but returning a ROW number just gets me part of the way there -- -I really need the 'Dependent User Story String' as the return item ...

Comment: I probably should have made it more clear .. that the From Key Dependency column (last column) is auto-generated based on an embedded formula that looks like this:

Comment: =IF(G6>4,CONCATENATE(B6,", ", B5, ", ",B4,", ",B3,", ",B2),IF(G6>3,CONCATENATE(B6,", ", B5, ", ",B4,", ",B3),IF(G6>2,CONCATENATE(B6,", ",B5,", ",B4),IF(G6>1,CONCATENATE(B5,", ",B6),CONCATENATE(B6)))))

Comment: It uses the count() in pkey4 (which indicates how many times pkey3 appears) - to generate the correct list of User Stories from the pkey column

Comment: ahh ... looks like the aforementioned actually returns a relative row number -- which could be very handy --- if I use offset to select the correct row - and column --- thanks ...

Comment: @user2480076 Did you see my first comment? which column is the Key Dependancy column? Assuming that column is column H then you can use LOOKUP similar to Jack's suggestion to find the last occurrence of "CALMS-7175" in column D and return the corresponding value from H, i.e.`=LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D="CALMS-7175"),H:H)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table is sorted on pkey3, this should work:

Use the following formula for the "running concatenation" in column F

```
=IF($D2<>$D1,$B2,$F1&", "&B2)
```

Then in Column G

```
=INDEX($F:$F,MATCH($D2,$D:$D,1))
```

should populate with the last concatenated string

*EDIT*

Additionally can get fancy and ensure that the concatenated string doesn't contain duplicates by using this formula in column F

```
IF(D2<>D1,B2,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,F1)),F1,F1&", "&B2))
```

Comment: Key piece is using the ",1" parameter in the match function.